# gensim with different context

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I'm using the [gensim library for word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). I want to train the model on text examples that are unrelated, for example: "The cat is brown. What time is it?"

I have created the following input to the model:

`[["The", "cat", "is", "brown"], ["What", "time", "is", "it"]]`, however I'm wondering whether the model assumes that "brown" and "What" are in the same context.

Tried to find the answer in the api, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gensim API won't consider "brown" and "What" in the same context. Uneven windows are used near sentence boundaries. So, for your example, if the window size let's say is 1, the (context, target) pairs would look like as below:

`([cat],The), ([The,is],cat), ([cat,brown],is), ([is],brown) ([time],What), ([What,is],time), ([time,it],is), ([is],it)`

I hope this clears your doubt.